# How to show Duplicate Records to users who do not own that record?

Tags: lightning-web-components, leads, duplicate-management, roles

**Problem Statement:**

I have users operating in different countries. They will create leads specific to their own countries. However if someone in Australia creates a Lead with Lead Name = 'Amazon' for example and then someone from Belgium create a Lead with same Lead Name = 'Amazon'.

That Belgium user will only receive a Salesforce warning with a generic message like "Duplicate Rule caused by duplicate Lead Name".

**Feasible?**

Is it possible that I can show that Belgium user **who the Lead Owner** is? (e.g the Australian user's name/email) so he can contact that person directly?
What is the simplest way this can be achieved?

Comment: Write a trigger, have your own error message